# Eclipse Kepler + maven + websphere 8.5 + JAX-WS

Tags: eclipse, maven, jax-ws, websphere-8

I have an ear maven project which contain an ejb moudle which has 4 stateless session beans annotated as web services. I was doing all my testing in Glassfish and have never complained when i deployed the ear file. Glassfish published the ejb's as web services and generated the WSDL and life was pink.

However, when i tried to deploy the same ear in WAS 8.5 nothing is published, and i can see the status of the service has x icon and when i hover it, it says that the service endpoints are not listening but the deployed asset is running.

I have spent a 3 day trying to solve this but no progress.

Have anyone faced such a problem? how you solved that and managed to publish the ejb as a web service?

Comment: You should place ejbs in web module

Comment: Sami, do i need and further amendments to web.xml or anything than just place my web service ejbs in web module?

Comment: Web.xml isnt actually required. You should have ejb-jat.xml though (admin console throes exception, if you don't)

Comment: Thank you Sami, I just need to confirm something. Is what you are saying specific to websphere only? Since i deployed the ear in glassfish and the ejb web services were packaged as a jar (ejb module in ear) and glassfish never complained. Also, i do have an ejb-jar.xml to set some environment entries and inject them in the ejbs, but that console exception you talk about is common in all AS's or just websphere?

Comment: As a side note, if you do your testing in [WebSphere Liberty Profile](https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/downloads/websphere-application-server-liberty-profile/), you should experience fewer surprises and incompatibilities at deploy time - it's designed for super-easy-start up and deployment, to make life easy for development, but it's also designed for fidelity with the full profile.

Comment: Admin console exception is WebSphere specific. Packaging local ejb's inside a WAR is part of Java EE 6 web profile: http://jaxenter.com/introducing-the-java-ee-web-profile-36201.html

Comment: Thanks Holly,I do use WAS 8.5.5 for developers ILAN. But i think Websphere is not stable and have lot of issues because of caching.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone later who may face the same issue. there is a utility in websphere/appserver/bin called endptEnabler. You must run it on your ear before installment in the app server.. Good luck for all

Answer (score 0):

while deployment of webservices you have to enable the check box "Webservice" available in deployment settings in websphere